# C++, I want to know how to allocate memory vector< pair<int, int> > *

Tags: c++, memory, vector, new-operator, allocation

I have an error _Has_unused_capacity() vector...
I don't know how to allocate dynamic memory

I try to push_back, but the error occurred

```
vector< pair<int, int> > * v;

void Some_Function(){
   int m=3;
   int idx1=1;
   int idx2=2;
   int idx3=3;

   for(int i = 0; i<m; i++) {
       v[idx1].push_back(make_pair(idx2, idx3));      
       v[idx2].push_back(make_pair(idx1, idx3));
   }
}
```

Comment: Simply use `vector< pair<int, int> >  v;` instead of a pointer. The `std::vector` will manage memory properly for you if you use it correctly: `v.push_back(make_pair(idx2, idx3));`

Comment: This is not vector but a pointer to a vector

Comment: Why are you trying to use a C-style array of vectors? Don't do thaṫ. Don't use C-style arrays at all.

Comment: The point of using a vector is to **avoid** using pointers. Just use a vector, not a pointer to a vector.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a poiter to a vector which points to nowhere. Either allocate memory for your vector ( not recommended though) or don't use a pointer.

```
vector< pair<int, int> > * v = new vector<pair<int, int>>[2];
V[idx].push_back(make_pair(idx2, idx3));
```

Don't forget to delete your vector when you are done with that.

```
delete [] v;
```

The better way is using smart pointers, here is an example with `shared_ptr`:

```
#include <iostream>

#include <vector>
#include <memory>

using namespace std;
using vecPair = vector<pair<int, int>>;

// deallocator for an array of vectors
void deleter(vecPair* x)
{
    delete[] x;
}

int main() {
    shared_ptr<vecPair> v;
    v.reset(new vecPair[2], deleter);
    int a = 1;
    int b = 2;
    int c = 3;
    int d = 4;
    v.get()[0].push_back(make_pair(a, b));
    v.get()[1].push_back(make_pair(c, d));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

At first, I don't recommend you to use pointer to container.

Also, the element is pointer may cause memory leak.

But, if must. you can use `std::vector<std::vector<std::pair<int, int>>`

OR, `auto vec = std::make_shared<std::vector<std::vector<std::pair<int, int>>>()`

use smart pointer may manage memory by itself. `std::make_shared` has been support since C++14